# How to properly read a filename from STDIN in Linux Assembly Language?

Tags: linux, parsing, assembly, x86, tty

I'm going through a book named Programming from the ground up by Jonathan Bratlett. This book teaches assembly language for x86 processors and the linux operating system using GCC toolset.

In unit 7 which teaches about error handling, you are asked to modify an existing program to add a **recovery mechanism for the program that allows it to read from STDIN if it cannot open the standard file already hard coded in the program.**

The **problem** here is that user entered filename from the STDIN is **appended with \n at the end by default.** So the program does not find the file to read from.

I have to **replace the \n with 0 manually in the program for it to work.** And it does not feel like the proper way to handle this situation. How do I go about solving this problem properly?

PS: This is my first time asking a question here. Please let me know If I can improve the question in any way. Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
.include "consts/linux.s"
.include "consts/record-def.s"

.section .data
input_filename:
    .ascii "wrongtest.dat\0"
output_filename:
    .ascii "testout.dat\0"

.section .bss
.lcomm record_buffer, RECORD_SIZE

.section .text
.equ ST_INPUT_DESCRIPTOR, -4
.equ ST_OUTPUT_DESCRIPTOR, -8

.globl _start
_start:
    movl %esp, %ebp
    subl $8, %esp

    movl $SYS_OPEN, %eax
    movl $input_filename, %ebx
    movl $0, %ecx
    movl $0666, %edx
    int $LINUX_SYSCALL
    movl %eax, ST_INPUT_DESCRIPTOR(%ebp)    #Input descriptor.

    cmpl $0, %eax
    jg continue_processing
    .section .data
    no_open_error_code:
        .ascii "0001\0"
    no_open_error_message:
        .ascii "Could not open the file\0"

    .section .text
    pushl $no_open_error_message
    pushl $no_open_error_code
    call error_exit
    addl $8, %esp

    movl $SYS_READ, %eax
    movl $STDIN, %ebx
    movl $record_buffer, %ecx
    movl $RECORD_SIZE, %edx
    int $LINUX_SYSCALL

    ###Manually replace last byte of the filename with 0###
    #decl %eax
    #movb $0, record_buffer(,%eax,1)

    movl $SYS_OPEN, %eax
    movl $record_buffer, %ebx
    movl $0, %ecx
    movl $0666, %edx
    int $LINUX_SYSCALL
    movl %eax, ST_INPUT_DESCRIPTOR(%ebp)    #Recovery input descriptor.

    continue_processing:
    movl $SYS_OPEN, %eax
    movl $output_filename, %ebx
    movl $0101, %ecx
    movl $0666, %edx
    int $LINUX_SYSCALL
    movl %eax, ST_OUTPUT_DESCRIPTOR(%ebp)   #Output descriptor.

    start_inc_age_loop:
        pushl ST_INPUT_DESCRIPTOR(%ebp)
        pushl $record_buffer
        call read_record
        addl $8, %esp   

        cmpl $RECORD_SIZE, %eax
        jne end_inc_age_loop
        incl record_buffer + RECORD_AGE

        pushl ST_OUTPUT_DESCRIPTOR(%ebp)
        pushl $record_buffer
        call write_record
        addl $8, %esp
        jmp start_inc_age_loop
    end_inc_age_loop:
        movl %ebp, %esp
        movl $SYS_EXIT, %eax
        movl $0, %ebx
        int $LINUX_SYSCALL
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal to need to manually handle newlines in terminal / file input.  `read` system calls just give you access to the raw byte stream, no parsing.

That's why it's normal to take filenames from command-line args (like `cat foo.txt`), rather than a list of files from stdin.

And why in Unix shell programming, you definitely want to avoid parsing filenames out of a text stream: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead - and why things like `find -print0` and `xargs -0` to use `\0` as a separator exist.

`\n` is a legal character that can appear in filenames, so the only way to safely/unambiguously parse filenames from stdin is to separate them with the one byte that can't appear in filenames, `0`, the C string terminator.  (Or to use some kind of format with explicit lengths, so you'd know the next 123 characters were all filename regardless of what they were.)

---

For a single filename, you could also expect the user to end their input at the end of the filename, e.g. submitting TTY input by pressing the EOF character (control-D by default, run `stty` to show terminal modes).

Then you can directly use the result of `read()` into an already-zeroed buffer as a C string.  (Except that still doesn't fully let you handle newlines in filenames with the terminal not in raw mode; the user typing a newline would cause the terminal input to be submitted, i.e. `read()` would return.  However, the user can work around that by using control-V to make the next character "literal", letting them hit <kbd>^V</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> to type a literal newline without submitting input with the TTY in "cooked" canonical mode.  Try it yourself typing into `cat` or `strace cat > /dev/null` on a terminal, along with what happens when you type control-D on a non-empty line (read returns non-zero), vs. on an empty line (or after a previous control-D) to make read return zero, i.e. EOF)

Comment: Thank you for such high quality answer :-)